# Trying to Connect Power BI Service to Snowflake - What IP address does the PBI service use?

Tags: powerbi

I am attempting to connect my PBI service to an instance of Snowflake. We have Snowflake set up to only allow certain IP addresses. I am not able to connect from the PBI service and am getting a credentials error. However, I think the real problem is the IP address the PBI service is using isn't being allowed by Snowflake. How can I find out what IP address(es) the PBI service is using so I can whitelist them in Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single IP address for Power BI. The azure services are running in a range of IP addresses, which by definition are dynamic and can change in time. You can get the current IP address range for the public cloud here - [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). For Power BI and Power Query it contains hundreds of address ranges. However, even if you allow them all, it is not something that you should allow once and forget. You should review this list, because this file is updated weekly. This is the inconvenience of having database and Power BI in different cloud providers. If both was in Azure, you can manage the network traffic by service tag and not by specific IP address.